RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
I have been trying to reproduce the results of this repo-
https://github.com/sefcom/VarBERT/tree/main
I was able to train the BERT model for MLM objective. But in the Constrained Masked Language Model training I'm consistently facing an error -
`/home/hprakash/.conda/envs/HP/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/optimization.py:429: FutureWarning: This implementation of AdamW is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use the PyTorch implementation torch.optim.AdamW instead, or set `no_deprecation_warning=True` to disable this warning
  warnings.warn(
05/14/2024 06:58:30 - INFO - __main__ -   ***** Running training *****
05/14/2024 06:58:30 - INFO - __main__ -     Num examples = 4509495
05/14/2024 06:58:30 - INFO - __main__ -     Num Epochs = 30
05/14/2024 06:58:30 - INFO - __main__ -     Instantaneous batch size per GPU = 32
05/14/2024 06:58:30 - INFO - __main__ -     Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 32
05/14/2024 06:58:30 - INFO - __main__ -     Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
05/14/2024 06:58:30 - INFO - __main__ -     Total optimization steps = 4227660
05/14/2024 06:58:30 - INFO - __main__ -     Starting fine-tuning.
Epoch:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                           | 0/30 [00:00<?, ?it/s/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1711403408687/work/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu:250: nll_loss_forward_reduce_cuda_kernel_2d: block: [0,0,0], thread: [26,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.t/s]
Iteration:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                   | 0/140922 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
Epoch:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                           | 0/30 [00:01<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hprakash/VarBERT/varbert/cmlm/training.py", line 944, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/hprakash/VarBERT/varbert/cmlm/training.py", line 892, in main
    global_step, tr_loss = train(args, train_dataset, model, tokenizer)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hprakash/VarBERT/varbert/cmlm/training.py", line 488, in train
    outputs = model(inputs,labels=labels)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hprakash/.conda/envs/HP/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hprakash/.conda/envs/HP/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hprakash/VarBERT/varbert/cmlm/training.py", line 139, in forward
    masked_lm_loss = loss_fct(prediction_scores.view(-1, vocab_size), labels.view(-1))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hprakash/.conda/envs/HP/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1511, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hprakash/.conda/envs/HP/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1520, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hprakash/.conda/envs/HP/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 1179, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/hprakash/.conda/envs/HP/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 3059, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered
Compile with `TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA` to enable device-side assertions.`

I ran the training file on the CPU and got this error-
IndexError: Target 50001 is out of bounds.


I found some articles online where it was said this is caused due to discrepancies between the model's expected vocabulary size and the size defined in tokenizers config. I made changes accordingly but the error still persists. I need to figure this issue out to be able to further train the model.

I can't tell you where you're going wrong, but I can tell you that this is a vocab size issue.
Your target value in your loss contains the value 50001.
Your target values are attempting to index into your model output tensor, which is of size (bs, C, ...) where C is the number of items in your vocab. For your model, C < 50001, so you get an indexing error.
You need to set your model up so that the size of the output matches the size of your vocabulary. You should inspect the size of the model output, verify what size it actually is, then update the model config to use the correct size matching your vocab size.

Thanks for your comment. I was able to identify the root problem. I ran some scripts to find out the vocabulary size of the tokenizer, the output size of the model, and the vocabulary size of the model. The output for all of them was 50265. After that, I went through the training.py file and noticed that the vocabulary size was defined as 50001. I changed it to 50265, and now the error is resolved.
